# how to play audio after getting audio path in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I list all audio path from device storage now i want to play  audio from path .
**this is my listview code**

```
ListTile(
                    title: Text(files[index].path.split('/').last),
                    trailing: FutureBuilder<int>(
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
                      },
                      future: files[index].length(),
                    ),
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

To play audio I personally prefer [this flutter plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/just_audio)

And a sample use case is look like bellow code snippet.

```
  final player = AudioPlayer();

  player.setFilePath('FILE_PATH_HERE');

  player.play();                                  // Play without waiting for completion
  await player.play();                            // Play while waiting for completion
  await player.pause();                           // Pause but remain ready to play
  await player.seek(const Duration(seconds: 10)); // Jump to the 10 second position
  await player.setSpeed(2.0);                     // Twice as fast
  await player.setVolume(0.5);                    // Half as loud
  await player.stop();
```